# After releasing a WakeLock screen is not turned off

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I'm writing app which must show alert dialog. To wake up device I'm using:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "AlertWindow");
wl.acquire(); // wake up the screen
//... show alert to user
Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                wl.release(); // release lock 
                }
        }, TIME);
```

But the problem is when alert window is open, screen is not turn off automatically.

`adb shell dumpsys power` before alert show:

```
mLocks.size=0:
```

after show but not closed:

```
mLocks.size=1:
SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK        'AlertWindow'ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP  activated (minState=3, uid=10070, pid=5183)
```

Is there a way to turn off the screen using a handler? After closing the alert dialog lock is turned off ...

Comment: See also : stackoverflow.com/questions/13754820/android-wakelocks-in-4-2-for-flashing-the-screen-on-and-off